# How to align a table header with a table body after data loading into it

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am making a simple app in Angular 7 where I need to load data from a web service into a Table.

The problem is that the table headers does not align with the table body after loading this web service: https://randomuser.me/api/?results=25.

html

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:510px; width: 100%;">
    <div class="table-responsive" style="margin:auto;padding-top:10px;height:560px; width: 100%;">
      <table class="table table-borderless table-hover fixed_header">
        <thead style="color: black">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: white;" class="align-middle">Titulo</th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: white;" class="align-middle">Mensaje</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor='let alerta of homeService.Alerta'>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ alerta.name.first | uppercase }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ alerta.email }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
.fixed_header thead, tbody { display: block; }

.fixed_header tbody {
    height: 450px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc9dR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of your answer:

**In .css file**

```
//remove **display:block** 
// if you don't want heading in center, then apply css as below 
.fixed_header thead, tbody { text-align: left }


.fixed_header tbody {
    height: 450px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes that fix the problem, but now my headers are not static ;

Comment: Headers are not static in the sense ? Can you explain that ?